# Logged on as one user and deleted records from a table. Another user logged in can still see records. How?

Tags: mysql, delete-row

Details:
I have 2 users `(qa_user, dev_user)` with the same privileges in the `mysql.user` table.
I have no other settings for these 2 users in the following tables: `mysql.db, mysql.host, mysql.tables_priv, mysql.columns_priv and mysql.procs_priv`.

logged in as `qa_user`:
I delete the records from a table `address`.

```
delete from address where zip = '10019';
```

I have another user, `dev_user`, logged in:
That user can still see the records with `zip = '10019'`
I've done everything with this user by logging out and logging back in.

I use `TOAD` as my IDE and connecting to the database server with both users.

Comment: Without further information, this sounds like some sort of caching issue.  Is there any caching happening between the client and your MySQL database, to your knowledge?

Comment: Can the user who deleted the rows see them, or just the 2nd user?

Comment: Seems like the transaction is not commited

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the client is really just TOAD that I'm using to query the db directly. So, not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @SloanThrasher the first who deleted the rows can't see them, but the 2nd user does.

Comment: @lucumt I will look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. With @TimBiegeleisen's commentary regarding caching. I looked into MySQL cache.

```
FLUSH QUERY CACHE;
```

Running the SQL statement above, quickly cleared up the cache results and initialized the cache. More info can be found [FLUSH_QUERY_CACHE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flush.html#flush-query-cache)